# Cómo funcionan estos operadores en JS

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cómo funcionan los operadores `>>>`, `>>`,`<<`. Sé que tienen que ver con los bits de los números a comparar pero realmente no sé cómo usarlos.

Comment: ¿Colocarías por favor el fragmento de código donde los estás intentando usar?

Comment: No lo estoy usando. Es solo que vi un desafío por ahí y me dio curiosidad saber sobre esto. Solo quiero saber cómo se usa.

Comment: Aqui los tienes [ejemplo 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_(Desplazamiento_a_la_izquierda)), [ejemplo 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E_(Sign-propagating_right_shift)) y [ejemplo 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift)) de un sitio muy bueno con ejemplos y teoría

Answer (score -4):

Esos operadores son de desplazamiento de bits, por ejemplo 15>>>2 desplaza los bits de 15, 2 posiciones a la derecha, introduciendo ceros por la izquierda, resultando 3

Por ejemplo.

```js
console.log(0b1111>>>2);
console.log(0b1111<<2);
```

0b1111 >>> 2 = 0b0011 (3 en decimal)

0b1111 << 2 = 0b111100 (60 en decimal)

La diferencia entre >> y >>> es que con >>> entran 0's y con >> mantiene el msb para mantener el signo (o sea, si el número es negativo, entran 1's, en caso contrario 0's).

Con << desplazas a la izquierda y entran 0's.

Ten en cuenta que en js las variables son de 32bits (actualmente, que yo sepa)

Por ejemplo, con ~0>>>1 obtendrías el mayor numero posible (Si inviertes los bits de 0, obtienes todo 1's, desplazando 1 bit a la derecha, obtienes el mayor número positivo, ya que si el MSB es 1, indica que el número es negativo).